# what is the differens between two terminals, like pts/3 and pts/5

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

The linux command 'jobs' seems like will show the commands running background.   I type like "emacs &"  then "jobs" I can see it. But if i type "jobs" at others terminal, it turns out nothing working background.
And in different terminal, typing ">history" they show different results. Why?
I try to "man jobs", but there is no manuals about jobs.

Comment: pts = pseudo-terminal

Comment: This might be better asked on/moved to http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands like "`jobs`", "`bg`", "`fg`", "`kill`", "`wait`" are all built-in shell commands for job control and are only related to the shell that is currently running. See: http://linuxcommand.org/lts0080.php

- When you are connected to **pts/3**, you run a shell (say, *bash*) in that terminal and you get a command prompt, and can start processes, and type commands, etc.
- When you are connected to **pts/5**, you run another shell (also *bash*) in that terminal, and you get another command prompt, which you can start processes and run commands, etc.

They are different bash processes, each with its own command history and jobs. That's why you can't see the background processes in one bash process from the other one. They're two separate running bash processes.

Answer (score 0):

jobs is discussed in 'man bash'. Each bash session has it's own history. If 'jobs' shows no background processes then there are none for that bash process.